# Subsection alignement problem using 'verse' package

Tags: miktex, verse

I'm stuck into a 'newbie' problem:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,a5paper,twoside,openright,italian,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}

\ifpdf
\usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\fi
\usepackage{tikz}
\ifxetex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\fi

\DeclareRobustCommand\ltseries
{\not@math@alphabet\ltseries\relax
    \fontseries\ltdefault\selectfont}
\newcommand{\ltdefault}{l}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlt}{\ltseries}

\DeclareRobustCommand\hbseries
{\not@math@alphabet\hbseries\relax
    \fontseries\hbdefault\selectfont}
\newcommand{\hbdefault}{hb}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texthb}{\hbseries}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\FSfont}[1]{%
    \fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{#1}\selectfont}

\newcommand*{\labelit}[1]{\phantomsection\label{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\boxminipage}{%
    \@ifnextchar [%]
    \@ibxminipage
    {\@iiibxminipage c\relax[s]}}
\def\@ibxminipage[#1]{%
    \@ifnextchar [%]
    {\@iibxminipage{#1}}%
    {\@iiibxminipage{#1}\relax[s]}}
\def\@iibxminipage#1[#2]{%
    \@ifnextchar [%]
    {\@iiibxminipage{#1}{#2}}%
    {\@iiibxminipage{#1}{#2}[#1]}}
\let\@bxminto\@empty
\def\@iiibxminipage#1#2[#3]#4{%
    \ifx\relax#2\else
    \setlength\@tempdimb{#2}%
    \def\@bxminto{to\@tempdimb}%
    \fi
    \leavevmode
    \@pboxswfalse
    \if #1b\vbox
    \else
    \if #1t\vtop
    \else
    \ifmmode \vcenter
    \else \@pboxswtrue $\vcenter
    \fi
    \fi
    \fi
    \bgroup
    \hsize #4
    \hrule\@height\fboxrule
    \hbox\bgroup
    \vrule\@width\fboxrule \hskip\fboxsep 
    \vbox \@bxminto
    \bgroup
    \vskip\fboxsep
    \advance\hsize -2\fboxrule \advance\hsize -2\fboxsep
    \textwidth\hsize \columnwidth\hsize
    \@parboxrestore
    \def\@mpfn{mpfootnote}\def\thempfn{\thempfootnote}\c@mpfootnote\z@
    \let\@footnotetext\@mpfootnotetext
    \let\@listdepth\@mplistdepth \@mplistdepth\z@
    \@minipagerestore\@minipagetrue
    \everypar{\global\@minipagefalse\everypar{}}}

\def\endboxminipage{%
    \par\vskip-\lastskip
    \ifvoid\@mpfootins\else
    \vskip\skip\@mpfootins\footnoterule\unvbox\@mpfootins\fi
    \vskip\fboxsep
    \egroup
    \hskip\fboxsep \vrule\@width\fboxrule
    \egroup
    \hrule\@height\fboxrule
    \egroup
    \if@pboxsw $\fi}
\makeatother

\newlength{\tpheight}\setlength{\tpheight}{0.9\textheight}
\newlength{\txtheight}\setlength{\txtheight}{0.9\tpheight}
\newlength{\tpwidth}\setlength{\tpwidth}{0.9\textwidth}
\newlength{\txtwidth}\setlength{\txtwidth}{0.9\tpwidth}
\newlength{\drop}

\newenvironment{showtitle}{%
    \begin{boxminipage}[c][\tpheight]{\tpwidth}
        \centering\begin{vplace}\begin{minipage}[c][\txtheight]{\txtwidth}}%
            {\end{minipage}\end{vplace}\end{boxminipage}}

\newcommand{\editor}[1]{\def\@editor{#1}}

\author{Author}
\date{2016}
\title{BookTitle}
\editor{Editor}

\newcommand*{\titleRF}{\begingroup
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \FSfont{5bo}
    \drop = 0.2\txtheight
    \centering
    \vfill
{\Huge BookTitle}\\[\baselineskip]
{\large Author}\\[0.5\drop]
{\Large Ed. Editor}\par
{\large\scshape 2016}\par
\vfill\null
\endgroup}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\backgroundsetup{%
    contents={\ifnum\value{page}=1 \else \eachpageornament \thepage\fi},%
    position=current page.north east,%
    firstpage=false,
    angle=0,%
    scale=1,%
    opacity=0.5%
}


\newcommand{\eachpageornament}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,color=Brown]
    \node[anchor=north west](CNW) at (current page.north west){%
        \pgfornament[width=2cm]{61}};
    \node[anchor=north east](CNE) at (current page.north east){%
        \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{61}};
    \node[anchor=south west](CSW) at (current page.south west){%
        \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{61}};
    \node[anchor=south east](CSE) at (current page.south east){%
        \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{61}};
    \pgfornamenthline{CNW}{CNE}{north}{87}
    \pgfornamenthline{CSW}{CSE}{south}{87}
    \pgfornamentvline{CNW}{CSW}{west}{87}
    \pgfornamentvline{CNE}{CSE}{east}{87}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\pagestyle{plain}

\renewcommand{\poemtitlefont}{\normalfont\large\itshape\centering} 

\begin{document}

\begin{showtitle}
    \titleRF
\end{showtitle}

\newpage

\tableofcontents

\include{Section1}

\include{Section1}

\include{Section2}

\end{document}
```

The typical 'SectionX' file:

```
\section*{SectionX}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{SectionX}

\poemtitle{Poem1}
\begin{verse}
    row1 \\
    row2
\end{verse}
```

Everything works fine besides generated **toc** ... it result rendered without the expected (by me) offset. The result is something like that:

```
Indice                       2
     Section1                3
     Subsection1             4
```

While I'm expecting something like that:

```
Indice                       2
     Section1                3
         Subsection1         4
```

*Verse* package suggest to use this command:

```
\renewcommand{\poemtoc}{subsection}%
```

but using it just 'remove' subsection from **toc**.

Another issue I'm facing is the usage of 'roman' page notation for title, index and preface sections... I tried in several ways but I always find the background of page 1 removed (that's not the title page as I need).

The instruction that 'cause' such problem is this one:

```
contents={\ifnum\value{page}=1 \else \eachpageornament \thepage\fi},%
```

in `\backgroundsetup` directive. Changing '1' with 'i' or 'I' lead to compilation errors.

Comment: I also tried using `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{SubSectionX}`but without success

Comment: `\renewcommand{\poemtoc}{subsection}` is fine. You have to increase additionally the level up to which sections are included into the toc by `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}`.

Comment: Regarding roman numerals: Add `\frontmatter` after `\begin{document}`, and `\mainmatter` after `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: `\frontmatter` `\mainmatter` wont fix that problem.. it always restart numbering of pages so you got two number **1** pages in the document and the `\backgroundsetup` statement will always produce the wrong background.

Comment: @gernot `\setcounter` worked! thnx.

Comment: You have a mess regarding `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. Remove all of these commands, and add a single `\makeatletter` immediately before your definitions, and a single `\makeatother` after your definitions. Or maybe better, move all the definitions into a file `mydefs.sty` (without the `\makeat...` commands) and include it by `\usepackage{mydefs}`.

Comment: After that, change the `contents` line that you mention above to `contents={\if@mainmatter\eachpageornament \thepage\else\ifnum\value{page}=1 \else \eachpageornament \thepage\fi\fi}`.

Comment: I suggest to use `\chapter` instead of `\section`, and `\section` instead of `\subsection`, since \chapter is the top sectioning level of the `memoir` class. Then the current section toc entries will become chapter entries and will look the same as the index entry. And you don't have to redefine `\poemtoc`.

Comment: I would like to create a custom package as you are suggesting.. I will ask you for some more infos

Comment: I changed the `\section` with `\chapter` and `\subsection` with `\section` as you suggested but now I got an extra empty page for every `\chapter`....

Comment: Add `article` to the document options, in the first line. Have a look at the [documentation of the memoir class](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf).

Comment: @gernot .. regarding the extra page I got what's the matter.. the **openright** parameter move chapter on odd numbered pages so the text open in the right side ... that's good.